# Displaying links for similar articles

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli

I have a page where I want to display articles like the one you're reading (randomly chosen articles from same subcategory). I want to use a php script but the server says I have an error. Here is my script:

```
$article = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sources WHERE ID = '$ID'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($article))
{     
code which works perfectly
$samecat = $row['Subcategory'];
}

$samecats = explode(', ', $samecat);
  foreach($samecats as $similar){
      $scat[] = "Subcategory LIKE %".$similar."%";
  }
  echo implode(' OR ',$scat);
$samearticle = mysqli_query($con,
"SELECT * 
FROM sources 
WHERE (".implode(' OR ',$scat).") 
AND NOT ID='$ID' 
ORDER BY Rand() 
LIMIT 0,3 ");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($samearticle))
 {
 echo "<a href='article.php?ID=".$row2['ID']."'>&raquo "
     .$row2['Headline']."</a>";
 }
```

The connection works perfectly because it works with other components but I have bug here  :(((

Any alternative solutions will be fine, but I think this way is better.

error is:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: Does server say what error it is?

Comment: Could you also post the error it gives?

Comment: You want to make sure that you have permission from the copyright owner of the sites you get articles from. You could be in legal trouble if you do this.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result error, 

I have permission, It's my page ))))) there is an article on that page too

Comment: @simonatrcl why are you assuming the articles are taken from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not particularly. But he does say "articles like the one you're reading" which isn't definitive but certainly suggestive. And there are people who don't know....

Comment: @simonatrcl you are on article page, and I want to show suggestive articles, if you read script you will see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

https://eval.in/96729

I simulated your code and viewed the sql you're generating. It's like this:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM sources 
WHERE (Subcategory LIKE %test% OR Subcategory LIKE %foo% OR Subcategory LIKE %bar% OR Subcategory LIKE %baz%) 
AND NOT ID='' 
ORDER BY Rand() 
LIMIT 0,3 "
```

You need singlequotes around your terms like:

```
Subcategory LIKE '%test%'
```

So you need to:

```
$scat[] = "Subcategory LIKE '%".$similar."%'";
```

Really you should [enable error reporting for your querying](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error).

Comment: Thank you so much, 5 minutes more and I would be became crazy <3 thank you